# Problem with client event on Telerik MVC Combobox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I have the following markup in an MVC 3 Razor view.  As is, the ComboBox renders properly, but doesn't drop down when I click the dropdown arrow.  If I remove the jQuery validate script references that are added to the view by the create view template, all works.  What could be wrong here?

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function provinceChanged() {
        var cityCombo = $('#Cities').data('tComboBox');
        cityCombo.loader.showBusy();

        $.get(url, { provinceId: e.value }, function (data) {
            cityCombo.dataBind(data);
            cityCombo.loader.hideBusy();
            cityCombo.enable();
        });
    }
</script>
```

...

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
        .Name("Provinces")
        .SelectedIndex(1)
        .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.ProvinceList, "ProvinceId", "Name"))
        .ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("provinceChanged"))
    )
</div>
```

Here is how reference jQuery, in my master layout:

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Styles/Blueprint/screen.css") rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Add("telerik.common.css").Add("telerik.vista.css"))
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

**RESOLVED:** I have no idea what else changed, but after putting the jQuery Validate references back just for a code sample, my code now works with them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-troubleshooting.html#jQueryValidate). You are probably using an older version of jquery.validate.js which conflicts with jQuery.fn.delegate.

Comment: The conflict is present only in older versions of jquery.validate.js. I suggest you paste the way you include jquery.validate.js. Could it be included *before* jquery itself?

Comment: I have added my <head> tag from the 'master', and amended my <script> blocks above to show the 'validate' references I had earlier removed.

Comment: I tried my code after putting the validate references back, and it now works with them.  I will never know what was wrong, but thanks for your assistance.

Comment: The ScriptRegistrar will include jQuery 1.4.3 by design if you don't disable it. Two versions of jQuery included at the same time will conflict for sure. To disable the automatic including of jQuery do this: <%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false) %>